# Javascripts not working in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

A simple javascript function is not working as expected for me

My function is bigger than this non-working similar simple example

My problem is bigger than this, but

```js
function tst() {
  alert("Hello Word")
}
```

```html
<button onclick="return tst()">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Why do you `return` in your  `onclick` ? There is no need to do so. This might be a problem in IE.

Comment: Add a semicolon to the end of the alert statement and remove the word 'return', as mentioned.

Comment: tested it on IE 11, no problems encoutered, the alert shows up as expected. Please, provide a code that reproduces the problem, since this one is ok. Also, explain what does *"don't working"* means.

Answer (score 0):

Add a semicolon to the end of the alert statement and remove the word 'return', as mentioned.

```
function tst() {
  alert("Hello Word"); // <- missing semicolon and typo on 'world'.
}

<button onclick="tst();">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `function tst() {   alert("Hello Word") }`
>
> `<button onclick="return tst()">Click me!</button>`

Your code works well on my side (using IE 11 , chrome and Microsoft Edge browser), please try to test the code using another browser (such as chrome and Microsoft Edge), check whether it's only not work in IE browser.

If it only not work in the IE browser, try to clear the cache and history to re-test the code. Then, [using F12 developer tools to debug the code](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/samples/dn255007(v=vs.85)) whether there has some error. Also, you could check whether you [disable JavaScript in IE browser](https://www.technipages.com/internet-explorer-enabledisable-javascript).

If it also not works well in all browsers, perhaps there has some error in your JavaScript code, try to use F12 developer tools to debug the code.